# Include my CSS files with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css, performance

I upload a picture of my problem. The page insights always says, that my CSS files are slowing down my sites download.

Whats the solution for this? How should I add these files with javascript, or async mode?

My JS files, like jQuery also, are at the body closing tag at the page bottom.

[image]

Comment: You should [edit] the text of that message into the question rather than including screenshots of text. That image is hard to read and "enter image description here" doesn't help blind users at all.

Comment: Try https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/ . If you dynamically load styles it is a good idea to inline critical styles (for visible part of your site before scrolling) in the head part of your html, that way viewers wont see un-styled content on first visit.

Comment: I tried to try it, but i dont understand it. What files sould i include from this library? I included the loadcss file from the src folder, and i get errror message, that loadCSS function dont exists.

Answer (score 0):

CSS resources are blocking by default, means the browser waits for the content to be available before rendering the page. To avoid this you can try to put the link tags at the end of your html file which can help. Next useful idea is to remove the media type (or better set it when done). Like this the browser loads the file but does not wait.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
   href="css.css" 
   media="none" 
   onload="if(media!='all')media='all'">
```

Or you load the complete sources async. Without any further lib you could do something like this at the end of your html file:

```
(function() {
  // caniuse requestAnimationframe?
  var raf = window.RequestAnimationFrame  ||
      window.mozRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame ||
      window.msRequestAnimationFrame;

  // defer loading of all non criticial CSS
  function deferLoad() {

    // put all relevant styles here
    var asyncStyleSheets = [
      '/stylesheets/async-stylesheet-1.css',
      '/stylesheets/async-stylesheet-2.css'
    ];

    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];

    for (var i = 0; i < asyncStyleSheets.length; i++) {
        var link = document.createElement('link');
        link.rel = 'stylesheet';
        link.href = asyncStyleSheets[i];
        head.appendChild(link);
    }
  }

  if (raf) {
    raf(deferLoad);
  } else if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener("load", deferLoad, false);
  } else if (window.attachEvent) {
    window.attachEvent("onload", deferLoad);
  } else {
    window.onload = deferLoad;
  }
})();
```

But be aware that you might split your CSS in a critical part (which need to be there before the page renders) and the non-crictical part which can be loaded after initial loading.

Comment: But i would like to add about 3-4 css files. And this js script will speed up my page?

Comment: @Dave599 A good idea would be to compress all CSS into one file, and yes loading resources will speed up the initial rendering. I have updated my answer

Comment: loadCSS( "css/font-awesome.min.css" );
loadCSS( "css/bootstrap.min.css" );
loadCSS( "css/jquery.bxlider.css" );
loadCSS( "css/style.css" );

Sould i make only one css file of these 3?

Comment: Yes you should, as less resources as possible, compressed - as long as you are not using HTTP/2.

Answer (score -1):

I fixed the problem with the loadCSS plugin.
https://github.com/filamentgroup/loadCSS/blob/master/src/onloadCSS.js

Comment: This is not an answer